# How to fill a textboxes with a list of data?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a textbox that I want to fill with data, but I am not sure of my code 
here's what I have:

```
<td> 
    <select ng-show="field.fieldType.id==6" ng-model="field.relation.id"> 
        <option value="null">----------</option> 
        <option ng-repeat="t in entities" value="{{t.id}}">
            {{t.entityName}} 
        </option> 
    </select> 
</td>
```

It doesn't work can any one help?

Comment: That is not a textbox by the way...You have a select element with options...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74266xs7/2/)**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="name in names" value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
   $scope.names = ["mike", "angelo", "teresa"];

})
```